# How do I save an array into string without all the data being mixed into a single line?

Tags: java, arrays, string, stringbuffer

If I had an array that had store these data

```java
String stringArray[] = {
        "Apple a Day Keep You Away",
        "Banana a Day Keep Her Away",
        "Cat like Dog"};
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    sb.append(stringArray[i]);
}
String str = sb.toString();
System.out.println(str);
```

I write like this is it going to become `Apple a Day Keep You AwayBanana a Day Keep Her AwayCat like Dog` Or I need to add and `\n` like this `sb.append(stringArray[i] + "\n")` in order to get something I want.

```
Apple a Day Keep You Away
Banana a Day Keep Her Away
Cat like Dog
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `StringBuffer`, you could also make use of a `StringJoiner` to append all strings with a separation character. This also prevents adding an extra new line after your last result

```
String stringArray[] = {"Apple a Day Keep You Away", "Banana a Day Keep Her Away", "Cat like Dog"};
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("\n");
for(int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++) {
    joiner.add(stringArray[i]);
}
String str = joiner.toString();
System.out.println(str);
```

You could even make use of the streaming api and append your results there with a newline.

```
String stringArray[] = {"Apple a Day Keep You Away", "Banana a Day Keep Her Away", "Cat like Dog"};

String str = Arrays.stream(stringArray).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since *Java 8* you can use [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) method:

```java
String stringArray[] = {
        "Apple a Day Keep You Away",
        "Banana a Day Keep Her Away",
        "Cat like Dog"};

String str = String.join("\n", stringArray);

System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
Apple a Day Keep You Away
Banana a Day Keep Her Away
Cat like Dog
```